# Can't Select other bones in pose mode + Spine bone doesn't select all bones even though it's the parent

Tags: armature, bones, parent

So I rigged my character so the arms and legs move with bendy bones.

The spine body is the parent of the arms and legs

When I go to pose mode and click on the spine bone, none of the other bones display the pose mode options and I have to manually click out back to object mode and select the arm or leg bone just to be able to pose them

In the pic below, I am selecting the spine bone and in pose mode. However, none of the arms or legs are in pose mode and I cannot select them either

[image]

here is a pic of my collections. The armature is the spine bone, then the arms and legs are located inside of that as well as the green body character I designed.

[image]

[image]

If I want to pose the arms, then I have to go back to object mode then select it , then go to pose mode. As you can see none of the other bones are highlighted and I cannot pose them without individually switching back and forth

Comment: are all your bones in the same armature? If they are you need to shift left click to select another bone, if they are not, then join these bones to the armature

Comment: oh wow all I had to do was shift + left click... thanks! I think i tried that in pose mode and that's why it didn't work, so I had to switch back to object mode first then shift click

Comment: @moonboots  the problem is when i tried to hide the armature, it only hides the spine bone and the arms and legs are still visible. Is that normal based on my collection set up?

Comment: please share your armature: https://pasteall.org/blend/